# Return a new variable in the same block as assigning it

Tags: javascript, variables, return, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

Is there a way to return a new variable in the same block as assigning it?

I have this inline if-statement and I want to return the variable right away, without having to declare it first. When doing it like this (see below) everything works fine, except that the linter eslint is complaining about that x is an unused variable.

```
const y = true
let x = '' 

return (x = y === true ? 'it is true' : 'it is not true')
```

I want to do something similar to this (see below), so I can remove the declaration of x and just return it in the same block as I am assigning it. This doesn't seem possible.

```
const y = true
return (let x = y === true ? 'it is true' : 'it is not true')
```

If there so way of doing this (something like above) is it preferred to structure the code in this way instead?

```
const y = true
let x = ''
x = y === true ? 'it is true' : 'it is not true'

return x
```

Thanks!

Comment: why do you need `x` at all in any of these cases? you can just `return (y === true ? 'it is true' : 'it is not true')`

Comment: @bryan60 Idk why I haven't thought about that... Gosh, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well `x` *is* an unused variable. You declare it, you initialise it, you assign it once, but you never read from it.

You'd write either

```
const x = y === true ? 'it is true' : 'it is not true'
return x
```

or (just dropping the variable altogether) simply

```
return y === true ? 'it is true' : 'it is not true'
```

Comment: Yup! I totally forgot that I could just do:
`return y === true ? 'it is true' : 'it is not true'`
Thanks!